# Find and replace in an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax method that returns HTML.

In that returned HTML I wish to replace certain divs with data.

I've looked at replaceWith but this seems to operate on dom objects only, not on HTML returned from an ajax call.

How can I replace certain divs inside the success method in an ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get-data',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        //find div with class .test and replace it with <div class"abc"></div>
```

Comment: `var dom = $(html); dom.find('.test') ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceWith()`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get-data',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var $html = $(html);
        $html.find('.test').replaceWith('<div class="abc"></div>');

        // work with $html as required here...
    }
});
```